# Can other people monitor my internet activity in the same WiFi network?

Tags: privacy, wifi

I have a tablet that I share the same WiFi with two other people/computers. I have installed the CM Security anti virus app, and also a cleaning app.

I think that my activities are being monitored by the people that I share with, is this possible with the security I have installed on my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else has control of the WiFi access point onward or you're using a shared authentication key then there's very little you can do to ensure that you're not subject to an eavesdropping attack. Somebody with the same credentials who catches the initial association packet will be able to read all further session traffic.

If in doubt, you can route everything via VPN to a remote host or always use SSL and check your certificates.

Comment: Hey thanks Jeff I appreciate your help and again sorry to say I've just started playing with this 7''tablet and unfortunately I don't know what you are talking about , at least you tried thanks again, OUT.

Comment: Wifi works like a hub, so everything can be heard by every one if they listen. They can snort/sniff and "wireshark" anything om the same broadcast domain. Ideally they need only watch the wired traffic upstream of the AP in "promiscous mode". It won't be encrypted (normally). They can then scan the dump (huge of course) at their leisure).