# Can my employer see my activity over their WiFi if I'm using the Tumblr app?

Tags: privacy, mobile, iphone, social-media

I have a great relationship with my employer and I don't think anyone is spying on me and I don't care if they read my email. But if I'm logged into their WiFi and I'm using the Tumblr app on my iPhone 6 to view photos and GIFs and occasionally message other Tumblr users, can my employer see the photos I view or the messages I send and receive inside the app?

I don't know that much about it but I was under the impression that using the app was different from visiting Tumblr's website on a computer when it comes to them tracking or viewing my specific activity?

Comment: This question essentially boils down to "does the Tumblr app use TLS"?

Comment: As for the website, they only use TLS if the owner of the blog turns it on: https://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/tumblr-adds-support-for-ssl-but-doesnt-turn-it-on-by-default/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible. Your company has multiple ways of monitoring employee activity and traffic that is passing through their network. Depending on the type of company you work for, if they are constantly monitored and audited, etc will have an impact on the likelihood. Of course, this will greatly vary in every company, and it's best to keep browsing safe-for-work while using their wifi. There are multiple techniques one can utilize to potentially slip under the radar of spying eyes, but generally that has the potential to backfire and raise more suspicion than it would if they just see you browsing Tumblr. I have seen employees at past jobs receive a quick email stating that they aren't utilizing their time correctly. Though like I said earlier, this varies from company-to-company so your mileage may vary.

Please see this question as well:
[Can other people monitor my internet activity in the same WiFi network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91045/can-other-people-monitor-my-internet-activity-in-the-same-wifi-network?rq=1)